# OS X second window won't stay open

Tags: macos, nswindowcontroller

I want to open a second window to act as a content editor for some of the fields in the main window of my app. I created a custom NSWindowController (called ItemEditor) with its own nib.

I open the new window with this code:

```
ItemEditor *editor = [[ItemEditor alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ItemEditor"];
[editor showWindow:nil];
[editor.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

The new window appears for an instant and then immediately disappears. Both the `initWithWindow:` and `windowDidLoad` of ItemEditor are called, but `windowWillClose:` isn't.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that you're using ARC... and nothing is holding onto your "`editor`" object after it's created.  That's why it's disappearing as soon as it's being created.

You need to make "`editor`" a "`strong`" property in your parent window controller.

In other words, declare it like this in the parent view controller's .h file:

```
@property (strong) ItemEditor *editor;
```

And replace the first line of your code snippet above with this:

```
self.editor = [[ItemEditor alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ItemEditor"];
```